# sha1 function gives weird output

Tags: c++, visual-studio, md5, sha1

I have this C++ program developed in visual studio, which should print out the SHA1 and MD5 hashes of a given string:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include "windows.h"
#include "conio.h"
#include "wincrypt.h"

char Buf [256];
DWORD BufSize;

LPSTR CreateHash(LPSTR tohash, ALG_ID alg)
{
    HCRYPTPROV hProv;
    HCRYPTHASH hash;

    if (CryptAcquireContext(&hProv, NULL, NULL, PROV_RSA_FULL,
        CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT))
    {   
        if (CryptCreateHash(hProv, alg, 0, 0, &hash))
        {
            if (CryptHashData(hash, (BYTE *)&tohash, sizeof(tohash), 0))
            {
                ZeroMemory(&Buf, sizeof(Buf));
                BufSize = sizeof(Buf);

                if (!CryptGetHashParam(hash, HP_HASHVAL,
                    (BYTE *) &Buf, &BufSize, 0))
                    printf("Call to CryptGetHashParam failed. Error: %d\n",
                    GetLastError());

            } else printf("Call to CryptHashData failed. Error: %d\n",
                GetLastError());

            if (!CryptDestroyHash(hash))
                printf("Call to CryptDestroyHash failed. Error: %d\n",
                GetLastError());

        } else printf("Call to CryptCreateHash failed. Error: %d\n", 
            GetLastError());

        if (!CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0))
            printf("Call to CryptReleaseContext failed. Error: %d\n", 
            GetLastError());

    } else printf("Call to CryptAcquireContext failed. Error: %d\n", 
        GetLastError());

    return Buf;
}

using namespace std;
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    cout << "SHA hash: " << CreateHash("Visual C++", CALG_SHA)<<endl;
    cout << "MD5 hash: " << CreateHash("Visual C++", CALG_MD5)<<endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

It compiles but when i run it, it shows weird output.

The output should be

```
SHA hash: 0e4abc18f9fb9d8d6d39f047dc20fbebd4a975bd
MD5 hash: f3be2f04531a477a4bb755f9f42c6f2e
```

But it prints

```
SHA hash: ü©á*ÀªvÍŒe²5Ê¥Å?•Â
MD5 hash: òù%•þîOú°b>«’
```

Why?

How can i solve this?

Comment: It's raw output as bytes rather than hexadecimal.

Comment: Unless you need to support XP, you should probably use the [Cryptography Next Generation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376210(v=vs.85).aspx) API which is easier and safer to work with, and exposes more algorithms.

Comment: @towr How can i convert raw output to hex output?

Comment: @Mgetz can you give an example?

Comment: @user3099950 there are plenty on MSDN but [here is a specific example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376217(v=vs.85).aspx). CryptoAPI is deprecated because it is limited and has export restrictions which the CNG API does not. Also both SHA1 and MD5 should not be considered secure anymore for any use.

Comment: Search the web and StackOverflow for "c++ print hex".

Answer (score 1):

The cryptography functions will store the output in raw bytes.  You are expecting your output in either Base64 or Hexadecimal encoding.  To get there, you need to call the function that will convert the raw binary data to a string of your desired encoding.  You can see a sample of how to do that [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9acac904-c226-4ae0-9b7f-261993b9fda2/cryptbinarytostring-returns-invalid-bytes?forum=vcgeneral).

(copied example)

```
CString BinaryToBase64(__in const BYTE * pbBinary, __in DWORD cbBinary)
{
    // Check input pointer
    ATLASSERT(pbBinary != NULL);
    if (pbBinary == NULL)
        AtlThrow(E_POINTER);

    // Check input size
    ATLASSERT(cbBinary != 0);
    if (cbBinary == 0)
        AtlThrow(E_INVALIDARG);

    // Request size of Base64 string
    DWORD cchBase64;
    if (!CryptBinaryToString(pbBinary, cbBinary, CRYPT_STRING_BASE64, NULL, &cchBase64))
    {
        AtlThrowLastWin32();
    }

    // Allocate a string with required size
    CString strBase64;
    LPTSTR pszBase64 = strBase64.GetBuffer(cchBase64);
    ATLASSERT(pszBase64 != NULL);

    // Convert binary data to Base64
    if (!CryptBinaryToString(pbBinary, cbBinary, CRYPT_STRING_BASE64, pszBase64, &cchBase64))
    {
        AtlThrowLastWin32();
    }

    // Release CString buffer
    strBase64.ReleaseBuffer();

    // Return the converted string
    return strBase64;
}
```

The function you'll want to call is [CryptBinaryToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379887%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Where did the OP mention Base64?

Comment: I didn't mention Base64, I did mention SHA1 and MD5. Anyway, what is _the function that will convert the raw binary data to a SHA1/MD5 string_?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I was in the middle of adjusting that since it appears his strings are actually hexadecimal.

Comment: @user3099950 CryptBinaryToString is the Windows Cryptography library function that does that.

Comment: @ZacHowland Can you make an example?

Comment: @user3099950 I copied the example from Microsoft's page for reference.

Comment: @ZacHowland What are pbBinary and cbBinary?

Comment: @user3099950 It is in the MSDN documentation.  pbBinary is the binary data (your encrypted data in bytes), cbBinary is the size of the binary data (the number of elements in the byte array).

Answer (score 0):

I print out the results byte by byte using:

```
   cout << hex << (unsigned int) result[i];
```

If you must print the return value from the function directly, then create a structure containing the result buffer and overload the `operator<<` to print the buffer in the structure.

Comment: The problem is that i would like to have the string in hex format without having to convert it at print-time as i'm planning to use that string to compare its values to other strings. Is that possible?

Comment: His hash will be an array of `bytes`, which are `unsigned char`s.

Comment: @ZacHowland: Without casting, how does one tell `cout` to differentiate between a C-style string (char *) and a byte?  I found many examples of my method by searching for "StackOverflow cout hex".

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Nevermind ... I was thinking `int*` ... lack of sleep catching up with me.